# Django Filterset data not cleaned as expected

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a `FilterSet` defined as such:

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework

class SomeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    id = filters.BaseInFilter()
    sort_by = rest_framework.OrderingFilter(fields=["name", "creation_date", "location"])
```

I use DRF to define API view. In the view, I access the filter data with `filterset = self.get_filterset(queryset)`. What I noticed:

- `filterset.form.data` gives me a QueryDict({"sort_by": ["name", "location"]} (for example)
- and if I run `filterset.form.cleaned_data.get("sort_by")`, I only get `"location"`

This is expected if I look at the doc for [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get) but this is clearly not what I would expect from the cleaning. Any idea how I could override this cleaning so I can keep all values passed as query params ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me answer was to override `value_from_datadict` from django-filters `BaseCSVWidget`.

I was then able to use `lists()` method from QueryDict instaed of `get()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering the wrong way, it is not:

```
?sort_by=name&sort_by=location
```

but:

```
?sort_by=name,location
```

in that case the `QueryDict` is thus:

```
QueryDict({"sort_by": ["name,location"]})
```

not:

```
QueryDict({"sort_by": ["name", "location"]}
```

Comment: Sure, it works with `?sort_by=name,location` but I need to handle the other case `?sort_by=name&sort_by=location`. I use swagger to generate some documentation and query is built this way.